# Can you have two subnets on a network with the same IP block?

Tags: networking, routing, ipsec, strongswan

I have a bunch of routing boxes on a network `10.9.9.0/24`. I'm testing out scenarios with IPSec and StrongSwan, and I'm scripting a way to efficiently run these scenarios. Right now, the script I run drops a pre-baked config file on each gateway box and opens a tunnel, where their NATs can talk to each other. These have at least one client on them each. The NATs are hardcoded as `10.0.30.0/24` and `10.0.40.0/24`.

I don't want to have to configure this differently on each set of routing boxes. Is it kosher to, on the same network (I've got like 10 of these things on my overarching `10.9.9.0/24` network), duplicate NATs to configure between each pair of boxes (`10.0.30.0/24` and `10.0.40.0/24`)? The NATs only have to communicate with their partner, not outside of it. I can see that issues might occur anyway, since the traffic might try to be routed out of the current box and into another one, but I don't know enough about networking to be sure.

Of course, I could just test one pair at a time (bringing down the other tunnels while I do each one) and that'd work fine, but it'd be sweet to have them all up and running at the same time.

Comment: This is like, a subnet, in a subnet, in a subnet.

Comment: I'm almost certain the answer to your question is no but I'm really not sure I understand the question.  You're using the term subnet several places where it's clearly not what you're trying to describe.  A subnet is a block of IP addresses.  I think you may need to look into [Network Address Translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to isolate each device just like a standard home router would isolate it from the internet if you're just going to duplicate IP addresses on everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have made sense to present one of these configurations in detail.

But in general there should not be a problem if the NAT adresses are linked to the tunnel addresses on each of those systems. Then the NAT addresses would not leave any of those systems via the regular network anyway.